# Multiple entries in a JTable from a Database

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, resultset

This is my first question here and I hope I am not repeating someone else's question. I will try and explain the problem as much as I can in the next few lines. Pardon my English if its really bad .

So I have here a JTable in which I would like to retrieve values from a database. So far I can add 1 value and I know why this is. The question is . How do I add multiple values to this table ?

This is the method I use in my operations to find a gun in a specific shop with its quantity

```
    public ResultSet gunSearch(String id, int qty, int storeId) {

    try {

        String s = "SELECT gunID, gunName AS \"Gun Name\", gunPrice AS \"Price\", SellCost AS \"Cost\", availableQty AS \"Amount Available\", "+qty+" AS \"Quantity\"  FROM Guns WHERE gunId = '" + id + "'AND storeId='"+storeId+"'";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(s);
        rset = pstmt.executeQuery(s);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error here at searchByProdId Operation "+ex);
    }
    return rset;
}
```

For my GUI I use the following code to display the information entered by the user

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource().equals(enterBtn)){
        String gunID = gunIdText.getText();
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantityText.getText());
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(op.gunSearch(gunID, qty, storeId)));
```

Whenever I click the Enter button the column of data is retrieved from the database. However if I re-enter another gunId and quantity , the previous column disappears and the new column of data is retrieved from the database.

How could I possibly , enter couple of different gunId's and quantitie's into the JTable ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `gunSearch` method only returns one result. You then completely recreate the `TableModel` from this one result, erasing whatever you had in the old model.

You'll need to concoct a new method that can take a `Collection<String>` (a collection of gun ids) and return a row for each id provided.

Alternatively, you can create a method that adds a gun to an existing `TableModel` rather than recreating the whole model from scratch every time. It depends on how you want the application to work, which option is better.